# Flutter's Flexible Behavior

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want the blue to be full.
But it only spreads up to half.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQsiB.png

```
class TestScene extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            fit: FlexFit.loose,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: const Text('1'),
            ),
          ),
          Flexible(
            fit: FlexFit.loose,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: const Text('1234567890123456789012345678901234567890'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The reverse will also fail.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rf00I.png

In both cases, it's nice.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/21ORb.png

Comment: Sorry, I can't post any images because I don't have at least 10 ratings.

Comment: Do you want to fill blue/red to remaining space or to have half half like blue and red 50% each without string size ?

Comment: No. I want to display all two strings of indefinite length whenever possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way ! (To take remain space)

```
String one='1',two='1234567890123456789012345678901234567890';


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      backgroundColor:Colors.white,
      body: Row(
        mainAxisSize:MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          one.length>=two.length ?
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Text(one),
            ),
          ):Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Text(one),
            ),
          two.length>=one.length ?
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Text(two),
            ),
          ):Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Text(two),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Or to maintain equal size with colors simply use Expanded in both widgets

Comment: I'm sorry, the text is only used in the examples for clarity and the truth is complicated. The problem this time is that there is room for space, but with two Flexibles you only get up to half the space.

Comment: You can replace one and with your text any way !?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the one that you want to fill the space by `Expanded`. If you want both red and blue to fill the row, wrap both of them with `Expanded` and give them their own ratio with the flex property

```
class TestScene extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              child: const Text('1'),
            ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: const Text('1234567890123456789012345678901234567890'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If red is a long text, the layout will collapse... I want to achieve a beautiful layout with the three patterns in the question.

Comment: Just wrap the red Container with Expanded.